# Meteor: Session Issue

Tags: session, meteor

The app I am working on is doing the following:

After user logs in, user can then enter data, then see data on screen. Logged in user can delete data as well and see the change on screen.

My issues are:

When user logs off and another user logs in using the same browser the data that was entered for the previous user appears. Have to refresh in order to see the data for the currently logged in user.

And

When the user logs off, closes browser and new user opens a new browser and logs in - no data appears at all. Have to refresh in order to see the data.

I am using publish and subscribe. I am using Session.set, get and equals successfully for highlighting a particular row(tr). I tried using session for the data, but no luck so far.
Spent some time researching,but unfortunately not having luck applying anything I read.

Comment: Maybe try cleaning session when user logs out Session.keys = {} and set necessary session vars when user logs in in Meteor.startup. If that doesnt work provide more code: subscriptions, helpers etc

Comment: Session.set to null when logging out helps. At least now within the same browser when logging out and back in nothing shows up until refreshing. Prior to that, the previous user's data would show up. Think I have some more reading to do.

Comment: Give us some code so ppl can help.

Comment: I think I see the issue. I created the logout button, so I could add session.set to null. However since I'm using meteor's logginButtons for loggingin I need to hook inside to set the session. Does Meteor allow you to add inside of their logginButtons?

Comment: Hook session.set to login button click event

Comment: yoKO You've been a great help so far, and thanks. Do you know how to hook into the logginButtons? http://www.artandlogic.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Account-info.png http://www.artandlogic.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Sign-in-email.png

Comment: After looking at this https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/packages/accounts-ui . I would try using 'click .login-button' in template event helper. Im using my own template so wont be much of a help here.

Comment: yoKO I came back to tell you thanks as I had a 'duh' moment and inspected the element and so I am good now. I found the id for the button I need to work with in the event. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct way to do this.

Use "this.userId" inside of the publish block.

Comment: ;) Next time provide some code with question. Will be much faster.